# how to get number of lines changed in a PR using gh cli command

Tags: github, github-cli

I would like to find a number of lines changed for a PR using the gh cli command.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `gh pr view <pr number> --json additions,deletions`
which will return something like

```
{
  "additions": 0,
  "deletions": 0
}
```

[Docs for reference](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view)